Start mysql server programmatically
I manually start mysql server in my Mac using below code
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start

However I wonder if there is any way to start without sudo. I want to start mysql server programmatically and I don't want reveal the sudo password in my code.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Have you tried changing ownership of the file to your user?

Edit file sudo conf file (/etc/sudoers at Linux) to allow the command for a user without password. See man 5 sudo.conf for details.

You can run mysqld as a non-privileged user. This is described in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/changing-mysql-user.html
If you want the uid of the mysqld process to be different than the uid of the user who starts it, you must use sudo. But you don't have to reveal the password to allow use of sudo. You can configure /etc/sudoers to allow a specific user or group to run commands (or a specific command) with sudo privileges.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file is a good intro to the sudoers file. It is not specifically about DigitalOcean, but I think a lot of how-to articles on that site are very well written.
You could also launch MySQL Server from another executable owned by root that has the setuid bit set.
